# Django. Refreshing part of the page with ajaxForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I am submitting forms via django forms and I want data to refresh on submit in a certain part of the page (div)

```
 $(function () {
    $('#post-form').ajaxForm({
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            $('#this').append('snippet.html')
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        }
    }) });
```

of an html snippet

```
<div id="this">

        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <th>Откуда</th>
            <th>Куда</th>
            <th>Водитель</th>
        </tr>

    {% for item in query_set %}

        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.des_from }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.des_to }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.driver }}</td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And here is "views" file

```
    def post(self, request):
        csrf_token_value = get_token(self.request)
        data = {}
        form = SchedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            data['result'] = 'Created!'
            data['object'] = {
                'price': obj.price,
                'driver': obj.driver_id,
                'des_from': obj.des_from_id,
                'des_to': obj.des_to_id,
                'date': obj.date,
            }

            return JsonResponse(data)

        else:
            return JsonResponse(form.errors)
```

The problem is I have a JsonResponse in view's return while on the INTERNET I've read that there are two solutions via render_to_response and render_to_string. But as far as I'm concerned to refresh data in forms you need render_to_string. I just don't see a way to include it in the return with JsonResponse

Comment: You're not doing anything with the json returned and `$('#this').append('snippet.html')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Json in this case rutrns values from django forms. with an append im trying to "refresh" the snippet

Comment: That's not what that does.  You are literally appending the string 'snipplet.html' to the page

Comment: then how do I refresh forms in that part of the code?